# read the character and pint it if not equal to ا

Tags: c++, c, file

i tried this code to read each character in text file and if the chracter =ا  print @

else print the character

```
void
preprocess_file (FILE *fp)

{
  char d;

    for (;;)
      { 
    d = getc (fp);
    if (d == EOF)
        break;
        if (d =='ا')
        printf ("@\n");
        else
    printf ("%c\n ", d);
      }
}

int
main(int argc, char *argv [])
{
    preprocess_file (stdin);

    exit (0);
}
```

but the output file is showing strange result as following

```
    ï
 »
 ؟
 ط
 §
 ظ
 „
 ظ
 …
 ط
 ¤
```

any help?

Comment: What's wrong with the code?  Indentation, for starters.

Comment: 1. You have `cc` in one place, and `d` in another.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a trivial problem that has already been discussed numerous times and the solution wouldn't have required anything but actually paying attention in class.


Comment: You are probably running into codeset and wide character input issues; the `'ا'` character has a Unicode value U+0267 which doesn't fit into a single byte.

Answer (score 1):

your problem is here

```
if (d ='ا')
```

you're assigning `'ا'` to `d`

you should `==`

```
if (d =='ا')
```

Comment: `d` being a `char` is fine to compare to another `char`, but not to a `char*`, which is what`"|"` is.  You need to replace the double-quotes with single-quotes.

Answer (score 1):

`if (d ="ا")`

For a comparison you want `==` instead of `=`, and a single character instead of a string literal, like `d == 'ا'`.

As-is, it's attempting to assign the address of a string literal (which must be non-null) to a `char`, then checking whether the result is non-zero. While it's possible that the conversion from pointer to char could produce either 0 or some non-0 value, it's probably going to produce a *consistent* value, so at least with a typical implementation, that code will always execute.

You also have a problem because you've defined `d` to be a `char` instead of an `int`. To do the comparison to `EOF` correctly, you really need to make it an `int`.

If I were doing this, I think I'd do it a bit differently--something on this general order:

```
int ch;

while ((ch=getc()) != EOF) // or: `while (EOF != (ch=getc()))`
   printf("%c\n", ch == 'ا' ? '@' : ch);
```

Comment: `d` is a `char`, not a `char*`, so it isn't necessary to dereference it.

Answer (score 1):

```
char d;
//...
if (d ="ا")
```

`d` is a `char` and you are assigning it to a character array of size 2.  So you are squashing memory (for one), and your comparison will always be non-zero, so your condition will always be true and you will always run the block under your if-condition.  What you wanted was

```
char d;

for (;;)
{ 
    d = getc (fp); // should be d, not cc
    if (d == EOF)
        break;

    if (d == 'ا') // note the SINGLE quotes
        printf ("@\n");
    else
        printf ("%c\n ", d);
}
```

Comment: I didn't notice it at first either (haven't done C-style I/O in a while), but to compare to EOF correctly, you want to change `d` to an `int` instead of a `char`.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Technically, yes.  Though, since EOF = -1, it *should* be okay to just do the `d == EOF` check.  Granted, `(int)d == EOF` would be more accurate - but that has always bugged me about the C character functions (why they decided to use `int` to manipulate `char` is beyond me).

Comment: @ZacHowland: d==EOF is *not* all right. The problem is that you can have a 255 in the input, which will get converted to a -1 as a char, but is *not* the same as a real EOF (and casting to an `int` won't help either). They used `int` so that EOF could/would be different from any value that could be read from the file.

Comment: But 255 is not a valid value for a `char` (`unsigned char`, yes, `char`, no).

Answer (score 0):

You should write: `if (d == 'ا')`

It's `==` and not `=` and it's `'|'` for the `char` otherwise it's a string.

Also, change `cc = getc (fp);` by `d = getc(fp)`. I don't know what's `cc`.

You may have some problems with that character, in particular if you save your file in UTF-8. But dealing with multiple bytes characters is difficult, in particular for a beginner. Have a look to that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1373520/1787973

Comment: i did but it showed strange character in output and when make the program it shows gcc -g -O -Wall -ansi -pedantic    ascii1.c   -o ascii1
ascii1.c: In function 'preprocess_file':
ascii1.c:19:12: warning: multi-character character constant

Comment: @user1200219 You character ا is not an ascii character and can't be held in a char. You probably need unicode support and I don't think you want to get into that at the moment. No offense.

Comment: Save your file in something that is not UTF-8. For instance ISO-8859-15.