# What must I know to handle UTF-8 in my C program?

Tags: c, utf-8, c99, c89, ansi-c

I have a C program that now I need to do support to UTF-8 characters. What must I know in order to perform that? I've always hear how problematic is handle it in a C/C++ environment.  Why exactly is it problematic? How does it differ from an usual C character, also its size? Can I do it without any operating system help, in pure C and still make it portable? what else I should have asked but I didn't? what I'm looking for implement is it: The characters are a name with accents(like french word: résumé) that I need to read it and put into a symbol table and then search and print them from a file. It's part of my configuration file parsing(very much .ini-like)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an awesome article written by Joel Spolsky, one of the Stack Overflow creators.

[The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Apart from that, you might want to query some other Q&A's regarding this subject, like [Handling special characters in C (UTF-8 encoding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373463/handling-special-characters-in-c-utf-8-encoding).

As cited in the aforementioned Q&A, [Tips on Using Unicode with C/C++](http://linuxgazette.net/147/pfeiffer.html) might give you the basics.

Answer (score 1):

Two good links that i have used in the past:

[The-Basics-of-UTF8](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/misc/misc/multi-lingualsupport/article.php/c10451/The-Basics-of-UTF8.htm)

[reading-unicode-utf-8-by-hand-in-c](http://zaemis.blogspot.gr/2011/06/reading-unicode-utf-8-by-hand-in-c.html)

valter